# Query Event Posts by Date

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, events

I am trying to query custom post type (Event) by the current date and the event's start and end date. I would like three options: current, upcoming and past. This is the code I am using, but it is not working correctly.

```
      $current = time();

    switch ($print_type) {
        case 'current':
            $meta_quer_args = array(
        'relation'  =>   'AND',
        array(
            'key'       =>   'event-start-date',
            'value'     =>   $current,
            'compare'   =>   '<=',

        ),
        array(
                    'key' => 'event-end-date',
                    'value' => $current,
                    'compare' => '>='
                )

    ); 
            break;
        case 'upcoming':
            $meta_quer_args = array(
        'relation'  =>   'AND',
        array(
            'key'       =>   'event-start-date',
            'value'     =>   date(),
            'compare'   =>   '>=',

        )
    );
            break;
        case 'past':
            $meta_quer_args = array(
        'relation'  =>   'AND',
        array(
            'key'       =>   'event-start-date',
            'value'     =>   date(),
            'compare'   =>   '<',

        )
    );
            break;
        default:
            $meta_quer_args = array(
        'relation'  =>   'AND',
        array(
            'key'       =>   'event-end-date',
            'value'     =>   date(),
            'compare'   =>   '>=',

        )
    );
            break;
    }

$query_args = array(
    'post_type'             =>   'exhibitions',
    'posts_per_page'        =>   -1,
    'post_status'           =>   'publish',
     'ignore_sticky_posts'   =>   true,
    'meta_key'              =>   'event-start-date',
    'orderby'               =>   'meta_value_num',
    'order'                 =>   'DESC',
    'meta_query'            =>   $meta_quer_args
);

$selected_events = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  It may be irrelevant to your situation but the most common date query problems I see are related to the format used for storing the date.

Comment: The events don't seem to be sorting correctly. They all show up for the upcoming option and none on the rest. I think it may be a date format problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need type casting for custom fields **event-start-date** and **event-end-date**. Then it will compare with time() & date() value. You need to add `'type' => 'DATE',` in your meta query args. So your meta query will be like this:

```
switch ($print_type) {
        case 'current':
            $meta_quer_args = array(
        'relation'  =>   'AND',
        array(
            'key'       =>   'event-start-date',
            'value'     =>   $current,
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare'   =>   '<=',

        ),
        array(
                    'key' => 'event-end-date',
                    'value' => $current,
                    'type' => 'DATE',
                    'compare' => '>='
                )

    ); 
            break;
        case 'upcoming':
            $meta_quer_args = array(
        'relation'  =>   'AND',
        array(
            'key'       =>   'event-start-date',
            'value'     =>   date(),
            'compare'   =>   '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE',

        )
    );
            break;
        case 'past':
            $meta_quer_args = array(
        'relation'  =>   'AND',
        array(
            'key'       =>   'event-start-date',
            'value'     =>   date(),
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare'   =>   '<',

        )
    );
            break;
        default:
            $meta_quer_args = array(
        'relation'  =>   'AND',
        array(
            'key'       =>   'event-end-date',
            'value'     =>   date(),
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare'   =>   '>=',

        )
    );
            break;
    }
```